# how to dowload a file(i.e. textfile,doc or pdf) from a website into an Xcode app?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3

I 'am trying to download a file from a website and view it in an Xcode app. Does anyone know how to go about this? All I have seen is upload a file from local directory into Xcode app, but what about a file from a website. 
(i.e.) I can go to a website with my desktop and download a text or doc file and view it, but what if I wanted to do this with an Ipad? how would I go about it?
thanks